# how to "extract" mysql view object?

Tags: mysql, view

I want to dump only view object from mysql databases in the following format :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW 
`v_sample` AS 
SELECT
  `a`.`id`                  AS `id`,
  `a`.`code`                AS `active`,
  `a`.`title`               AS `title`
FROM t_test a;
```

the script above is the best practive i have ever had... no problem with privilege issue like can not drop the temporary view table, etc

Notes :
I found inside the dump script database, that mysql treat the view object as table first then will be replaced by the real view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [SHOW CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-view.html) statement.

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW v_sample
```

Comment: @zerkms : thnks for your response, can it be run on one command for all views ?

Comment: @yuda: nope, I don't think so. But you can just loop over all existent views.

Comment: @yuda: according to documentation - nope. I don't see any possibility to extract *only* views. So you will have to strip out tables manually.

Comment: @zerkms : i have already build small apps to generate views formatted as i mentioned above.. but i still can not order the views in order the column dependencies :( do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: @yuda: I'd better just parse mysqldump result

Comment: @zerkms : i have already did.. i just want to know if you have another efficient method.. thnks for your response anyway.. :)